# C# 6.0 and null

Tags: c#, null, c#-6.0

Trying to refactor following code:

```
var items = Common.Deserialize<DiagnosisItem[]>(path, false);
if (items != null)
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var find = _items.Where(o => o.Value.Tooltip == item.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (find.Value != null)
        {
            find.Value.Text = item.Text;
            find.Value.Color = (Color)converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(item.Color);
        }
    }
```

Talking about `null` checks. Seems `C#` 6.0 doesn't add anything new for it. Was thinking *"Oh, great, we have `?.` and `?[]` now! Should be cool!"* and then like ... hmm, but it does not happens often to have right side expression...

Am I wrong? Can this code become a bit more beautiful?

Comment: Would this question be better suited to codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: `.Where(o => o.Value.Tooltip == item.Id)` would fail if `Value` was null, so either that is wrong, or the `find.Value != null` check is not necessary. You do need a `find != null` check though.

Comment: You could add curlies `{ }` to your `if` block for a start...

Comment: You are using a lot of imperative statements. If you make this a query a lot of the mess goes away. I still see no use for the ?. operator, though.

Comment: A concise way of annotating parameters and return values to indicate that they can't be null together with an automatic check would have been 10x more useful than the `?.` operator.

Comment: You could replace the null check on items with `items ?? Enumerable.Empty<DiagnosisItem>()`, or if that situation is common, you could even add an `IEnumerable<T> OrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)` extension method.

Comment: @poke, code is not for review (not complete), only `null` parts bugs me. `_items` is dictionary, therefore  `FirstOrDefault` may return dictionary entry with `null` as a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually like to put as much as possible into queries because queries are more composable than statements.

```
var items = Common.Deserialize<DiagnosisItem[]>(path, false);
var updates =
 from item in items.NullToEmpty()
 join find in _items on o.Value.Tooltip equals item.Id
 where find.Value != null
 select new { find.Value, item };

foreach (var u in updates)
{
    u.Value.Text = u.item.Text;
    u.Value.Color = (Color)converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(u.item.Color);
}
```

Here, I see no need for the new null operator.

As a nice side-effect the quadratic time complexity of the `FirstOrDefault` thing is gone.

Comment: Thanks, this looks much prettier, though I am not a big fun of sql-alike syntax at least for now. Where is this `NullToEmpty` defined? Is it your own extension method or what? Having such basically will eliminate any need of null check before any `foreach`, could be pretty useful.

Comment: Yes, it's mine and I consider it essential. Alternatively: `items ?? Enumerable.Empty()` or `items ?? new Item[0]`. Both are not as nice.

Answer (score 2):

C# 6 a side, I personally prefer the following approach whereby you invert your if statements in order to reduce arrow code.

```
        var items = Common.Deserialize<DiagnosisItem[]>(path, false);

        if (items == null)
            return;

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var find = _items.Where(o => o.Value.Tooltip == item.Id).FirstOrDefault();

            if (find.Value == null)
                continue;

            find.Value.Text = item.Text;
            find.Value.Color = (Color)converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(item.Color);
        }
```

P.S. This would be better suited on the codereview site

Comment: As @poke mentioned in comment to OP, there should be a check on whether or not `find` is null before checking `find.Value`.

Comment: Well, you still have same `null` checks, only moved code outside of `if`, making it more *plain* (which is good, less indentation). But that's only cosmetic change and doesn't answer question. I am not asking for code review, but for `null` checks (sorry if that is not clear).

Comment: @RickDavin yeah you are right. I was just trying to make a point about reducing arrow code and therefore making it slightly more 'beautiful'

Comment: @Sinatr unless my eyes deceive me, your question explicitly asks 'how can I make this more beautiful?' - which is surely synonymous with a cosmetic change?